# Docker containers on same host but different bridges can't connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, routes, iptables, zabbix

I have (2) Docker-Compose configs running on the **SAME** host but **DIFFERENT** Docker bridges. Each are on different subnets so their traffic must be routed. One Docker-Compose config is for a containerized website, while the other Docker-Compose config is for a Zabbix Agent to monitor the website Docker-Compose config.

Although the Docker host they both live on has routes in the Gateway Router to both subnets, the Linux Docker host itself is also configured as a router, so should route traffic between the subnets it hosts.

Why can't traffic pass between different bridges on the **SAME** Docker host?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

## Intro:

Before implementing containerized monitoring, I had no prior requirement to pass traffic between docker bridges on the same host. I'm a Linux & network engineer and this wasted an hour of my life trying to understand how things were breaking, so I imagine if you're *not* a network engineer, you'll waste a lot more time- or fail completely. Thus felt it was worthy of a moment to document.

## Short Answer:

Docker was being "*helpful*" - ***again***- by automagically inserting `iptables` rules in the *DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 & 2* Chains in the FORWARD table breaking connectivity. Delete these rules and connectivity between containers raised on different bridges assigned to different subnets on the same host can now be achieved.

## Longer Answer w/ Proofs:

### Diagnostics:

I re-cut the image for the Zabbix Agent including some diagnostic tools- ***traceroute***, ***inetutils-ping*** & ***iproute2***- and after logging into the container with `docker exec -u root -it <container ID> bash`, I found the Agent's container couldn't ping the containers on the other bridge despite `ip route list` proving there was a correct route out of the Agent's container.

A review of the Docker host's firewall rules revealed that passing traffic between the Docker Bridges is **DISALLOWED** *by design*:

```
iptables -nvx -L --line-numbers

<SNIP>
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      530374 174564169 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        3559  5117334 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-2dfcb90fe695 !br-2dfcb90fe695  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3     1229457 499057258 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           


Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1           0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2          16      960 DROP       all  --  *      br-2dfcb90fe695  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3      533917 179680543 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0   
<SNIP>
```

If the source & destination of traffic are **NOT** the same for our Docker bridge in *DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1*, then it matches the chain's rule 2 which passes it to Chain *DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2* where it matches rule 2 here and drops the traffic.

We know this rule is having effect as we can see the packets incrementing for it; traffic is indeed being dropped. So Rule 2 in *Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2* if the offender.

### Solution:

Print the rules so we can determine the rule numbers of the `iptables` busting our connectivity:

```
sudo iptables -nvx -L --line-numbers
```

Then delete the problematic rules by their respective numbers. Note the final number "2" at the end of each `iptables` command is the rule number you want to delete. We'll delete both the target and the referring rule:

```
sudo iptables -D DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 2
sudo iptables -D DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 2
```

**WARNING**: Although restarting containers will **NOT** cause the deleted `iptables` rules to be recreated, doing a `docker-compose down` followed by an `up` **WILL**.

Hope this saves others wasted cycles figuring out broken container network connectivity...

Comment: There is some info on this on Docker website but it is far from complete: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/
It is possible to just insert rules into DOCKER-USER to achieve the same effect for a particular network instead of deleting docker-managed rules for all docker networks?